# Broadcast receiver and pending intent : Show a toast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

The following is the code for an alarm that has to hit the `BroadCast Receiver` :

```
Intent intentWithData = new Intent(context, TokenActivity.class);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.ID,id);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.POSITION, finalI);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 007, intentWithData, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

The code for the `Broadcast receiver` is

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TokenBroadcastReceiver extends BaseBroadCastReceiver {

String Id;
int position;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Create a toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

The manifest is  :

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcastReceiver.TokenBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

The toast is not showing up. Where am I going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 16):

You're mixing 2 things.
If you want your receiver to get the intent:

```
Intent intentWithData = new Intent(context, TokenBroadcastReceiver.class);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.ID,id);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.POSITION, finalI);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 7, intentWithData, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

if you want your activity to get the intent:

```
Intent intentWithData = new Intent(context, TokenActivity.class);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.ID,id);
intentWithData.putExtra(Constants.POSITION, finalI);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 7, intentWithData, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

Plus, make sure your receiver is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: is there any way to do both? My problem is that i can pass to `NotificationBuilder `only `PendingIntent` as listener of click, there I have to build TaskStackBuilder in order to open Activity, but I want simultaneously send request to the server in BroadCast, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Start your broadcast receiver inside your activity

Comment: Why are you using AlarmManager. Can you please explain?

Comment: That was in the original question

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the pending intent to open an activity as per your code

```
Intent intentWithData = new Intent(context, TokenActivity.class);
```

and displaying the toast in broadcast receiver. Please correct your code and it will start working.

```
    Intent intentWithData = new Intent(this, TokenBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intentWithData.putExtra("id",5);
    intentWithData.putExtra("position", 4);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 007, intentWithData, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

Don't forget to register your broadcast in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcastReceiver.TokenBroadcastReceiver"/>
```